# EJB 2.1 Entity how to get List not Collection?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm using ejb 2.1 BMP, JBoss 7.1 AS
I need to get List ordered by some field(it depends on user choice)
from database using ORDER BY in SQL statement.
Home Interface:

```
public interface AliveHome {  
    ...  
    Collection<Alive> findAllConstraint(...) [exceptions];  
    ...
}
```

When i change return type to List i get exception:

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to java.util.List
$Proxy13.findAllConstraint(Unknown Source)

But i need List (because with HashSet there is no sense in ORDER BY)
How to get List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution for JBoss 7. I just install JBoss 6
and it works with return type List !
=)

Answer (score 1):

A hashset is unordered, so you can't get an ordered list from it automatically. You need to iterate over the hashset, adding the items to a list, then order that list as you require.

Comment: or create your own ArrayList and call `arrayList.addAll(collection)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a `LinkedHashSet`? I think that works in EJB3 at least.

Comment: I must use 2.1 version. And how I can cast HashSet to LinkedHashSet?